# Get Matrix 2D from Matrix 3D with a given choice of the third dimension corresponding to the first dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, array-indexing

I have:

- A matrix 3D: A = (m, n, k).
- An array of choices for the third dimension corresponding to each index of the first dimension. idn = (m, 1) (wherein the value of any idn is a random integer in [1,k].

I need to capture the 2D matrix B (m,n) wherein the referred third dimension to A is taken from the corresponding choice. For example:

```
idn(1) = 1;
idn(2) = k;
idn(j) = k-1;
```

Then:

```
B(1,:) = A(1,:,idn(1)) = A(1,:,1);
B(2,:) = A(2,:,idn(2)) = A(2,:,k);
B(j,:) = A(j,:,idn(j)) = A(j,:,k-1);
```

Since idn is not constant, a simple `squeeze` could not help.

I have also tried the below code, but it does not work either.

```
B = A(:,:,idn(:));
```

It is very much appreciated if anyone could give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with [`sub2ind`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) and [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), but the simplest way I can think of is using [linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) manually:

```
A = rand(3, 4, 5); % example data
idn = [5; 1; 2];   % example data
ind = (1:size(A,1)).' + size(A,1)*size(A,2)*(idn(:)-1); % 1st and 3rd dimensions
ind = ind + size(A,1)*(0:size(A,2)-1); % include 2nd dimension using implicit expansion
B = A(ind); % index into A to get result
```

Comment: Many thanks, Luis. The code seems to work well for the given example. But if I change the size of A, for example, `A=rand(4,4,5);` and `idn = [5;1;2;4];`, the error `Index exceeds the number of array elements` is notified. Kindly give me further instructions.

Comment: In trying to understand the algorithm, I guess the fourth line could be: `ind = ind + size(A,1)*(0:size(A,2)-1);`. Please advise me further. Thanks.

Comment: @RomalpaAkzo Yes, it is as you say, sorry for the misttake. I just corrected it